# How to restrict uploading image by its file size and image resolution in SharePoint image library

Tags: sharepoint-online, image-upload

How to restrict uploading image based on its file size and image resolution in the custom image library using the "Validation Settings" feature available OOB.

Resolution restricts with =AND([Picture Height]>50,[Picture Width]>50) but not working.

Answer (score 2):

**First,** the `file size` is **not** a supported field in the `validation settings`.

Check also, [THE SUPPORTED AND UNSUPPORTED COLUMNS IN SHAREPOINT CALCULATED COLUMN FORMULA AND LIST VALIDATION SETTINGS.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

> **Note:** The maximum file size you can upload to a SharePoint Online site is 15 GB per file. unfortunately, you can't modify this limit as we
>   can do in SharePoint On-Prem because it's a shared setting for all the
>   tenants. also, there are no OOTB settings to adjust the file size limit per document library.

**Workaround**

Create a remote event receiver on item Adding to check the file size before upload.

---

**Second,** The Picture Height & Width are supported in the `validation settings`.

> **BUT**, you should be aware of the validation doesn't fire on item upload, it's fired on item save / check-in.

So your formula `=AND([Picture Height]>50,[Picture Width]>50)` should work but not as expected, where the file should be first uploaded, then the validation will be executed when you hit **SAVE** or **CHECK-IN** button as shown below:

[image]

I think this should be also helpful because you will not be able to **save** or **check-in** your files until matching the correct dimensions. in this case, you will be forced to upload a file again to match the validation settings.